# Run two simulators with the same device and iOS version concurrently

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I want to run two iPhone SE's running iOS 10.3 at the same time to compare two version of my app conveniently.  I've cloned the app repo twice with both repo's checkout on different commits.  I specifically created two iPhone SE devices in Xcode's Window/Devices menu.  When I run one app, I set the scheme to the one device, when I run the other app, I set the scheme to the other device.  But when a second app runs, it cuts off the first app.  I don't understand this.  The projects are different, and the devices are different so what is the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

If you grab Xcode 9 Beta, this should “just work” for you.  This support was added in Xcode 9.